# Binomial Distribution and Proportionality.

Tags: probability, statistics

I understand pretty well the concept of Bernoulli experiment and binomial distribution. However today I faced a question like this one.

A traffic engineer is studying a left-turn lane that is long enough to hold $7$ cars. Let $X$ be the number of cars in the lane at the end of a randomly chosen red light. The traffic engineer believes that the probability that $X=x$ is *proportional*  to $(x+1)(8-x)$ and $x= 0,1, \dots 7.$

Of course, the first thing I wanted to do was set up a PMF that allowed me to see the probability, however, I was confused by "proportional".

Can someone clarify this idea please?

Any help is greatly appriciated.

EDIT: hold one, now I am 
wondering, is it even binomial?

Answer (score 2):

The distribution is certainly not binomial. That the pmf is *proportional* to the given expression means that $P(X=x)=k(x+1)(8-x)$, where $k$ is such that $P(X=0)+\dots+P(X=7)=1$ to satisft the requirement of a probability distribution to sum to 1 over all events. $k=\frac1{120}$ here.

Comment: Thank you so much! but let me just clarify, if it is not binomial what is it?

Comment: @boby It is just another distribution without a name.